# Is there a way to allow concurrent remote desktop users on XP without changing dlls?

Tags: windows-xp, remote-desktop, windows-registry

I would like to allow concurrent users on an XP install, but I was wondering if there was a way to do it with out swapping dll's and booting into safe mode.

(Registry changes are fine)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No**, that's not possible. The restriction is hard coded into the terminal server dll's provided with Windows XP. The only way to get around that is to replace them with a previous version (one of the early beta versions of Windows XP didn't have that restriction).

Answer (score 4):

It's not possible to do it without patching or replacing DLLs. But some people have made "patches" and automated the procedure.

One example is the "**TerminalserverNoRestrPatch**", available at some places on the Net, including [here](http://ticpu.net:8080/~jerome/Windows/TerminalserverNoRestrPatch-1-2/).

*Beginning of their info.txt file:*

> ## Terminal server No Restriction Patch 1.2
>
> **Purpose**:  Remove all limitation of the
>   Windows Remotedesktop/Terminalserver
>   service   because of some
>   'restrictive' windows version like XP
>   Home/XP Professional,     Small
>   Business... or limits expose by
>   licensing logic.
>
> **Usage**:    Backup C:\windows\system32,
>   termsrv.dll,  winlogon.exe,   mstscax.dll.
>
> Start TS-Free-1.1.exe.
>   Check patcher
>   output for error.
>   Reboot.

Comment: Link no longer works.

Comment: http://deep.bg/?c=p&l=2&d=99