# How to setup XP to allow more than 1 user to log on remotely

Tags: windows-xp, remote-desktop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to allow concurrent remote desktop users on XP without changing dlls?](https://superuser.com/questions/48061/is-there-a-way-to-allow-concurrent-remote-desktop-users-on-xp-without-changing-dl)

I have a virtual machine that I want to be able to have more than one user log on to at a time.

Can this be done?  If so how?

Comment: lol, I asked the same thing 6 months ago.  Kinda lame on me.  Sorry

Answer (score 1):

XP doesn't allow multiple simultaneous user sessions. If this is required you will have to switch to a server product or add VM's